# passing GET parameters with <f:param> and <f:paramView> in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

**SOLVED:** The issue was caused by the libraries added by the **Visual Web** plugin for **NetBeans**.

I was trying to test passing GET parameters through a backing bean to the same page with the following code:

```
<f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="link" value="#{testBean.link}"/>
 </f:metadata>
<h:body>
    <h:link value="Link 3" outcome="test" includeViewParams="true">
        <f:param name="link" value="3"/>
    </h:link>
    <h:outputText value="Parameter is #{testBean.link}"/>
    <h:outputText value="Param list: #{param}"/>

</h:body>
```

- The first problem is that the rendered link tag does not have the expected url `test.xhtml?link=3`, but `test.xhtml`.
- The second one is i've noticed that even if i enter the desired URL myself in the browser, the `#{param}` expression will evaluate to the expected list of parameters but `testBean.setLink` won't get called.

This is the code for the backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
    private String link = "";

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
        System.out.println("LINK: " + link);
    }

}
```

Now... I found a way of fixing this by adding `@ManagedProperty (value="#{param.link}")` to the the bean's field (and removing the `<f:metadata>` section from the jsf page) but from what i've read in other related posts the `<f:viewParam>` way should work just as well.

If you have any ideas on why these things happen i would be more than grateful... i've spent enough time on such a little annoying issue like this one :)

Comment: Although the construct which you're using there is somewhat strange, I can't reproduce your problem with Mojarra 2.1.16. What JSF impl/version are you using? Have you tried upgrading to the latest available?

Comment: @BlausC Thanks for the hint. I updated Mojarra but that wasn't the issue. I wanted to try out the **Visual Web** plugin for **NetBeans** and it added some old libraries (_JSF1.1/1.2 Support_ and others) that seem to have caused my problem.

Comment: @Cristi,you're using VWP(Woodstock) with JSF2.0? VWP died  with NB 6.7.1., so if you've gotten it to work, please share here.

Comment: @kolossus i managed to install visual web in netbeans 7.2.1, but it's JSF 1.2 so... sorry :)